# creat an instance of user control in cs class that is not a code behind of aspx page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am writing an app in asp.net,
i wrote a web user control (that is in \WebSite\UserControls\StudentAddressingTeacherUserControl.ascx folder)

Now i want to create an instance of this user control in a class (cs that is not a code brhind of a aspx page).

how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you want to create an instance, do you want to add it dynamically to a page?

Comment: yes i do i need it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create an instance, do you want to add it dynamically to a page?

```
public static void addStudentAddressingTeacherUserControl()
{
    Page p = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    if (p != null)
    {
        var path = "~/UserControls/StudentAddressingTeacherUserControl.ascx";
        var control = p.LoadControl(path);
        p.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need it in a class (.cs) that is not an aspx code behind so i dont have page.load

Comment: @user723686: I'm afraid that you didn't understand my approach. I'm getting the current page via `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` which can be used even in a static method(like in this example). This works as long as you're in a HttpContext(not in a Winforms application) and not using ASHX Handler instead of an ASP.NET Page. You can put this method even in a separate class library dll and you can call it from wherever you need(for instance a custom class).

Answer (score 0):

you could also simply

```
Control c = (this).LoadControl("/UserControls/StudentAddressingTeacherUserControl.ascx");
```